# Mongodb Replication Set and Database

Tags: mongodb

I'm MongoDB newbie, I used MongoDB 2.6.5 for awhile, my environment : 3 server: primary , second , Arb , 1 database DB1 (~ 3GB , 3 millions items) , 1 Replication Set : ReplicationSet1

```
                server1(primary)       server2(second)       server3(Arb)
DB1                   x                            x
ReplicationSet1:PRIMARY> rs.conf ()
{
        "_id" : "ReplicationSet1",
        "version" : 3,
        "members" : [
                {
                        "_id" : 0,
                        "host" : "server1:27017"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 1,
                        "host" : "server2:27017"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 2,
                        "host" : "server3:30000",
                        "arbiterOnly" : true
                }
        ]
}
```

DB1 is backup daily :
`mongodump --host server1 --db DB1 --out $BACKUP_HOME$DATE --oplog`
Now I want to create new database DB2 and force my app using it, DB1 will be used as read-only (not change/update anymore), so I will backup DB1 last time then backup DB2 daily.
How can I do that ?

Can I remove DB1 from ReplicationSet1 so only DB2 is replicated between primary and second ?

Can I create new Replication Set with DB2 only ?

Can I move DB1 to another instance (port 30001 for example) and run 2 MongoDB instances (27017 and 30001) at the same time ?

Please give me some advice and thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing that you want to create a new database DB2 and stop the writes to DB1 if this is the case then just go ahead and create a new database called DB2 and configure your application to only use DB2 for further inserts and reads, it is as simple as that mongodb can handle multiple database connections at the same time, so if you ever want to read data from the old DB1 database u just connect to that database and read the data and also since your not inserting any data to DB1 there will not be any replication happening on your DB1 database as well and as soon as you create DB2 it will be automatically replicated, you do not have to worry about that.

hope this helps and if you are trying to remove the primary machine and add a new primary machine, the steps are all together different, if this is what you want let me know, I will give them to you.

Comment: Thank you very much Aoxi,
I will create more DB2 in ReplicationSet1, since DB1 will be used as read-only (not change/update anymore) it will not affect replication traffic.
Then I will backup DB1 once last time and backup DB2 daily
<code>mongodump --host ip --db DB2 --out path</code>